# Style radio buttons once checked/selected

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the colour of radio buttons and button label when the radio button has been selected. Have tried this.

```css
input[type='radio']:checked {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```
    <label
                  className='tag-item'
                  key={tag}
                  htmlFor={`filter-${tag}`}
                  clickable='true'>
                  <span>{tag}</span>
                  <input
                    type='radio'
                    name='tag'
                    id={`filter-${tag}`}
                    value={tag}
                    checked={tag === currentTag}
                    onChange={e => setCurrentTag(e.target.value)}
                    className='tag-radio'
                  />
                </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the default Radio button's color.

But you can do this with some trick.

```css
input[type=radio]{
  display: none;
}

.fake-radio{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.fake-radio::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .fake-radio{
  border-color: red;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .fake-radio::before{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Tag</span>
  <input type="radio" />
  <span class="fake-radio"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: And is there a way to style the label if the radio button is checked?